# Registering helpers with EmberJS 2.0 without the use of Ember-CLI

Tags: javascript, ember.js

My team and I are developing an application with EmberJS 2.0.
Since we had specific requirements that Ember-CLI does not provide, we've developed our own solution with a Grunt task to compile our application.

With previous versions of EmberJS we used the following method to register new handlebar helpers:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('date-display', function(data, unix) {
    ...
});
```

The problem we now face is the deprecation of the registerHelper method within the Ember.Handlebars namespace. We now generate our helpers as such:

```
var dateDisplayHelper = Ember.Helper.helper('date-display', function(params, hash){
     ...
});
```

Our question is, how can we register this helper, to make it available in our handlebar templates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
App.DateDisplayHelper = Ember.Helper.helper(function(params, hash){
  return "foo?";
});
```

JSBin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kaqere/3/edit?html,js,output

Comment: So simple! Works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: May I ask where you found how to do this?  I've been scouring the ember docs for this answer.